# WebAPi Odata $select stopped working after class rename

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, odata

We are using **ASP.NET WebAPI with Odata (System.Web.OData 5.6.0.0)** connected to jquery datatables.
Everything was working until yesterday when **we renamed one of the classes** being queried - this is the only change we were able to identify.

Suddenly, the generated OData query was not working.
We investigated the endpoint using manual queries and found out that if we remove the "$select" part of it, everything works correctly.

These are our parameters, **just removing $select makes it work again**.

```
$format=json
$select=A,B,C,D,E
$skip=0
$top=20
$count=true
$orderby=A+asc
_=1443011814464
```

Comment: This question needs more elleboration. Edm model mostly. Is your schema still 'correct according what you think it should be'?

Comment: Hi, when I look at the $metadata, it is still the same, just the name of the entity was changed. And just tested, $orderby works on the very same properties. There must be something rotten inside $select implementation, otherwise I cannot explain this.